# Return a vector of values associated with a vector of character strings?

Tags: r

I have a data-frame of survey respondents from various countries. I would like to create a new vector with the average wage of in country, next to the respondent.

I have a data set of countries and wages - sample below:

```
countries <- c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", "Czech")
wages <- c(61620, 48306, 49419, 50033, 18645, 15374)
data_set <- data.frame(countries, wages)

  countries wages
1 Australia 61620
2   Austria 48306
3   Belgium 49419
4    Canada 50033
5     Chile 18645
6     Czech 15374
```

In my data frame there is a vector of the nationalities of the respondants:

```
c("Martha", "Shelagh","Ronald", "Stefan", "Dimitri", "Jack", "Johan", "Arnold", "Gilles")
c("Canada", "Australia", "Canada", "Czech", "Czech", "Australia", "Czech", "Austraia", "Belgium")
```

I would like to create a new vector, which returns the appropriate average wage for each country.

It should return something like:

```
 names   country av_wage
1  Martha    Canada   50033
2 Shelagh Australia   61620
3  Ronald    Canada   50033
4  Stefan     Czech   15374
5 Dimitri     Czech   15374
6    Jack Australia   61620
7   Johan     Czech   15374
8  Arnold   Austria   48306
9  Gilles   Belgium   49419
```

Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: `aggregate(wages ~ countries, data_set, mean)`

Comment: It seems that the OP is trying to `merge` the first aggregated df with a df with one row, that last vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the first aggregated data `data_set`.

```
countries <- c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", "Czech")
wages <- c(61620, 48306, 49419, 50033, 18645, 15374)
data_set <- data.frame(countries, wages)
```

Then, name the two vectors in such a way that the vector of countries shares the name with the corresponding vector of `data_set`.

```
names <- c("Martha", "Shelagh","Ronald", "Stefan", "Dimitri", "Jack", "Johan", "Arnold", "Gilles")
countries <- c("Canada", "Australia", "Canada", "Czech", "Czech", "Australia", "Czech", "Austraia", "Belgium")
new <- data.frame(names, countries)
```

Now just merge the two dataframes.

```
merge(data_set, new)
#  countries wages   names
#1 Australia 61620 Shelagh
#2 Australia 61620    Jack
#3   Belgium 49419  Gilles
#4    Canada 50033  Ronald
#5    Canada 50033  Martha
#6     Czech 15374   Johan
#7     Czech 15374  Stefan
#8     Czech 15374 Dimitri
```

To reorder the columns,

```
mrg <- merge(data_set, new)[c(3, 1, 2)]
mrg
#    names countries wages
#1 Shelagh Australia 61620
#2    Jack Australia 61620
#3  Gilles   Belgium 49419
#4  Ronald    Canada 50033
#5  Martha    Canada 50033
#6   Johan     Czech 15374
#7  Stefan     Czech 15374
#8 Dimitri     Czech 15374
```

Comment: Thank you - I was indeed looking for ```merge``` !!